# How to get Quadro RTX 6000 working in Dell EMC 8440 chassis?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, power, pci-express, nvidia

I need to install and power the (circa 2018) Quadro RTX 6000 (QR6) GPUs in a Dell EMC 8440.  The Dell 8440 uses the "Special 14 Pin to 8 Pin PCIe Cable" for GPUs, but because the QR6 is a desktop model it is not compatible with the special power cable.  The cable is made for passively cooled server-style GPUs, like the NVIDIA A40.

Link to 8440 gpu cable:

https://www.moddiy.com/products/Dell-DSS8440-PowerEdge-Server-Special-14-Pin-to-8-Pin-PCIE-Cable.html

There are 14 total pins on the QR6 (2x4 + 2x3).  See pics in link:

https://www.servethehome.com/nvidia-quadro-rtx-6000-gpu-review/

Looking for recommendations on how to force this undesirable configuration to work.  Are there any cables that make such a conversion?  I can cut/splice into the harness, but am having difficulty finding pinout information for the GPU side - would welcome information on that topic.

Background:  The GPUs shipped in a circa 2018 BOXX APEXX chassis.  I don't know why BOXX used desktop GPUs in a server, but perhaps it was the only option at that time.

Comment: You will have to use a multimeter and create your own pin map. Those GPUs are more workstation cards than server cards. Is the connector on the card not an 8-pin?

Comment: Was afraid of that (having to use dmm).  QR6 has 14 pins (2x4 + 2x3). Do you know where to find the card-side pin-out descriptions?  Will update post with this info.

Comment: Schematics are not often released by Nvidia partners. At least not anywhere you actually want to download from.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to contact Dell sales and see what kind of "GPU enablement kit" parts they may offer.

Although not recommended, due to stacking adapters and potentially overloading the 8-pin CPU connector/terminals, you could simply add a "CPU to dual 6+2-pin PCIE adapter" to the end of the Moddiy 8440 adapter. E.g. https://www.moddiy.com/products/CPU-8-Pin-to-2-x-PCIE-8-Pin-Splitter-Cable.html (preference for the 16AWG version) Overloading the power connector can cause melting of the terminal housing, which could occur on the motherboard/power distribution side of the connector

It's hard to tell visually, but it seems to appear, and is a common practice in servers, that Dell's power connector (motherboard/power distribution side) is smaller than a typical PCIe/CPU power connector housing used in consumer devices, which would make fabricating your own cable, even with the right housing and pin-out diagrams, quite challenging. If the Dell connector is the standard size, you could create your own adapter if you understand Dell's pinout.

The Quadro RTX 6000 comes in a few varieties with different power pinouts. The Desktop/Workation version uses standard PCIe power connectors. The Quadro RTX 6000 Passive uses a CPU 8-pin power connector ("EPS-12V'' below). Note that the sense pins are also connected to ground. A simple visual inspection of the GPU should confirm the version.  [image: GPU and CPU power connector pinout diagram] However, a DIY solution is not recommended due to unknown compatibility concerns with server power distribution and should only be considered "at your own risk."